# Rails - don't rollback certain parts of a transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to not rollback some parts of a transaction?

I'm trying to use an `after_validation` hook in a somewhat complex codebase where numerous parts are wrapped in a big transaction block. However, I want to save a log entry, regardless of whether the transaction as a whole fails and gets rollback.

I can't use `after_rollback` either, because that never gets called in certain instances.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) claims that it is Atomic - there is no need to split it into parts that can be rolled forward or back independently. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029165/is-after-validation-hook-called-every-time-on-active-record) SO thread you can get list of callbacks and choose which one suites your case to log needed info. Consider refactoring your code - split that operation into smaller operations (real transactions).